# How can I use the same identity provider for the two app services?

Tags: authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have two separate app services hosted in Azure. One of them is a website (ASP . NET) and the other is a web API. I set up an identity provider on the first web app (website) using the Authentication blade. This forces the user to log in to the application before she can access any pages.

**WebSite Authentication**
[image: App Service Authentication]

I want to also set up authentication on the web API. When I set up the authentication using an existing app registration in the directory, I am no longer able to access any of the web API services from the website. How can I use the same setup for both the app services and also access my service?

**WebServices Authentication**

[image: App Service]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the same identity provider for the two app services?

- Yes, We can use same Identity provider for the two App services.
- I have created and deployed two applications ASP.Net and Web API
- Added Identity providers for both the applications
- Tried to access the applications, got the below error while accessing the WEB API

```cs
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application
```

- In Azure Portal => Active Directory =>App registrations =>Under  Owned Applications , click on your application name  => click on  Redirect URIs, Under Add ***Redirect URIs***
- Add the redirect uri suffixed with `/.auth/login/aad/callback`
- Now Iam able to access both the applications without any errors

[image]

[image]

- ***Make sure to add both app service URLs in redirect URL option***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. How is the token passed from the webapp to the webapi? Is it seamless or do I need to make any code changes?

Comment: In step #3, you've added identity providers for both apps. How did you do this? Can you please provide some detail with a screenshot?

Comment: In Azure Portal => Active Directory =>App registrations =>Under Owned Applications , click on your application name => click on Redirect URIs, Under Add Redirect URIs

Comment: Check the above screen shots

Comment: Under Web , Click Add URI

Comment: I have checked the screenshots, but the call from the webapp to webapi is failing. I authenticated the user at the webapp UI. How will the authentication pass over to the webapi?